# Chat update if a new entry in the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

So i have a problem. A made a chat with php and mysql. But, if I enter a text, I can't see it in the other window because it is not updating. So I started to make a program with iframe, and i found it much cooler than the other. I'm using  to reload the frame all 2 seconds. Now my question is, how can I make this easier with javascript, so that the chat is updating automatically?

Code of the frame (I'm german, so it's a little bit confusing):

```
<?php

 require 'config.php';
 session_start();




?><head><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Studit</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="lobby.css"><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=/ownwebsite/lobby1embed.php"></head><?php 




$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM lobby1 ORDER BY id DESC";
        $abfrage_antwort=mysqli_query($con, $abfrage);


        if (!$abfrage_antwort)
        {
            die('Ungültige Abfrage:' .mysqli_error());
        }




        echo '<table border="1">';





while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($abfrage_antwort, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{ //row algorithm...}
```

Comment: use setTimeout(function(){ call_ajax_to_update(); }, 1000);  to run the ajax call and update the page .

Comment: @JYoThl: In my honest opinion – bad idea. He need loop, not delay only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval (functionRefreshingChat, 1000);` in javascript. 
It'll create infinite loop with delay 1000ms.

According to one of comments to your question: `setTimeout` is not solution. It'll execute inner function only once.